# create multi instance backward-timer jquery plugin in MVC razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have page view list like

```
     @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="colcode">

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SMCode)
                </td>
                <td class="colname">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td class="colip">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IP)
                </td>
               <td class="coloffsetfund">
                        <div>
                            <span id="@item.IP.Replace(".","")"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span id="@item.SMCode"></span>
                        </div>
                             <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(document).ready(function () {

                                    idtimer = '#@item.IP.Replace(".","")';
                                    password = '@item.Password';
                                    ip = '@item.IP';
                                    smcode = '@item.SMCode';
                                    startTimer(idtimer);
                                    $(idtimer).backward_timer({
                                        seconds: '@item.DelaySecond',
                                        on_exhausted: function (timer) {
                                            alert('stop timer:' + idtimer);

                                            //ajax call to update value
                                        }                                       
                                    });                                   
                                });
                            </script>
```

My list have 2 items but i dont know why. when event **on_exhausted** of timer excute, it always is the last item. i dont know what is logic here.How do I alert correct idtimer. thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

sry guys,
i knew where is my problem, because i use variable to assign value, and when generated HTML, the variable always contain lastest value. i fixed it when use direct call like

```
$('#@item.IP.Replace(".","")').backward_timer({
```

for other guy get problem same me :)
thank you.